# Different display interface on the same devices

Tags: android, user-interface

i make a info dialog and run it on emulator and myDevice ,That any two devices have the same profile:
**genymotion emulator :**

[image]

**my device (huawei mediapad x1 7.0) :**

[image]

but when you run application ,Output on any device is different :

**output on genymotion emulator :**
[image]

**output on my device :**

[image]

The same hardware specs but different output ,Why?!

Comment: I'm not sure about the Genymotion emulators, but the Android emulators used to report a different screen density depending on the scaling of the emulator window on your computer's display. (Don't know if they still do that.) Verify that your software is being told the expected density when running on the Genymotion emulator.

Comment: no any idea about this issue?